# Continued Square Root till n terms

Tags: java

how to do the following program using Java: 
**sqrt(2+sqrt(2+sqrt(2.....till n terms**

Please help me with it as fast as possible.
I am just a beginner in programming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recursion might be a concept worth looking into

Comment: can you please explain it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when `n=1` it means `sqrt(2)`, when `n=2` it means `sqrt(2 + sqrt(2))`.

```
double twoPlusSqrt(int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be greater than 0");
        } else if (n == 1) {
            return Math.sqrt(2);
        } else {
            return Math.sqrt(2 + twoPlusSqrt(n - 1));
        }
}
```

Comment: OP says "I am just a beginner in programming".  Is a solution using recursion the best thing to give such a person?

Comment: @DavidWallace I think that early exposure to recursion is good, and is the natural way that most programmers would approach this program.  If OP is trying to learn I think this is a good example of a problem, hopefully they will take the time to understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want the computer to do is to repeat the same two steps over and over - adding two and square-rooting the result.  Since when `n=1`, you want the result to be `sqrt(2)`, your starting value should be `0` - so that in the first step, you can add two, square-root the result, and finish with `sqrt(2)`.

So the simplest way to do this, without recursion, would be this.

```
double result = 0.0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++ ) {
    result = Math.sqrt(result + 2);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: @DavidWalace i think the program should have been: 
 double result, result1 = 0.0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++ ) {
    result = Math.sqrt(result1 + 2); result1=result;
}
System.out.println(result);

Comment: Really, it makes no difference if you use an extra variable like that.  But if you want to post that as an answer, why don't you go ahead?

Comment: Actually i asked the question a year ago...and now i found the solution to it. Hence i didnt write it, just wanted to clarify with you, Sir.